# Regex Pattern Priority

Tags: java, regex

I have set the pattern `Part\s[V|IV|III|II|I][:]?` the problem is that when it comes across `Part III`, for example, then it acknowledges `Part I` as the match and cuts out the other two `II`'s. Is there no way to make the `III` in the pattern have a higher priority so it's included in what's found?

Comment: This is not a valid regex for your problem. You are abusing character class for disjunction. Replace the brackets with parentheses. The brackets aroud `:` are redundant, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you have is that a character class (the [ and ]) only matches a single character. So it matches any one of the characters within it, in this case you've simply restated I quite a few times. What you need is to or multiple strings rather than characters. I.e.

```
(Part\s(V|IV|III|II|I)[:]?)
```

Note the round brackets instead of square ones.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `(Part\s(V|IV|III|II|I)[:]?)`